# Sort by Digit Length, then By Number Itself

Tags: javascript, sorting

How to sort an array of integers by their digit length in descending order, then settles ties by sorting numbers with the same digit length in ascending order.

Examples

```
digitSort([77, 23, 5, 7, 101])
➞ [101, 23, 77, 5, 7]

digitSort([1, 5, 9, 2, 789, 563, 444])
➞ [444, 563, 789, 1, 2, 5, 9]

digitSort([53219, 3772, 564, 32, 1])
➞ [53219, 3772, 564, 32, 1]
```

I tried to write my own sort function but it did not help!
Please help

Answer (score 2):

That's the code, if they have same length just return the smaller, otherwise return the longest one.

```js
function digitSort(arr){
  return arr.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.toString().length !== b.toString().length) {
      return b.toString().length - a.toString().length;
    }
    return a - b;
  })
}
```

Comment: beautiful!
. . . . .

Answer (score 1):

A numerical approach takes the logarithm of 10 as digit count.

```js
const digitSort = array => array.sort((a, b) =>
    Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(b))) - Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(a))) ||
    a - b
);

console.log(digitSort([77, 23, 5, 7, 101]));         // [101, 23, 77, 5, 7]
console.log(digitSort([1, 5, 9, 2, 789, 563, 444])); // [444, 563, 789, 1, 2, 5, 9]
console.log(digitSort([53219, 3772, 564, 32, 1]));   // [53219, 3772, 564, 32, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

````js
const digitSort = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => String(b).length - String(a).length || a - b)

console.log(digitSort([77, 23, 5, 7, 101]))                    //[101, 23, 77, 5, 7] 
console.log(digitSort([9, 667, 87, 56, 3023, 5555, 111]))      //[3023, 5555, 111, 667, 56, 87, 9]
```
````